# nftables, dnat in output chain appears to be done after routing

Tags: nat, nftables

I have an EC2 instance and an application that requires to send to the EIP from within the instance.

I am trying to configure a dnat on the output chain so that the packets dont go out to the internet and back.

I have tried with the following:

```
nft add table ip table
nft add chain table output '{ type filter hook output priority raw; policy accept; }'
nft add rule tgw-routing output oif "ens7" ip daddr "A.A.A.A" ip daddr set "B.B.B.B" accept
```

Where A.A.A.A is the EIP address and B.B.B.B is the private address on the EC2 instance.

If I do a packet trace, I can see the translation has taken place, but it is being sent to the MAC of the default gateway, as though the translation has taken place after its routing decision.

For more context, I am trying to replicate this iptables rule:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       all  --  anywhere             A.A.A.A  to:B.B.B.B
```

Which works how I want, but I've been told I cant use iptables so need an nftables solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `chain type` from `filter` to `route` - seems to resolve this for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).